# Replacing part of image with a mask in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that is 384x384 pixels.I want to mask out or replace everything in the middle of the image, so I just have the borders of the image. For this I have created a mask that is 352x352 pixels (just a black image). Now I want to place this mask in the middle of the image so it has a distance of 32 pixels to every corner.

I thought of something like this but it does not work:

```
mask = cv2.imread('C://Users//but//Desktop//mask.png')
hh, ww, dd = mask.shape

image = cv2.imread('C://Users//but//Desktop//Train//OK//train_image1.jpg')

x = 32
y = 352
print('left:', x, 'top:', y)

# put mask into black background image
mask2 = np.full_like(image, 255)
mask2[x:x + hh, y:y + ww] = mask

# apply mask to image
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask2)

cv2.imshow('masked image', img_masked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/but/PycharmProjects/SyntheticDataWriter.py", line 17, in <module>
mask2[x:x + hh, y:y + ww] = mask
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (352,352,3) into shape (352,32,3)
```

Comment: On the actual error: Why `y = 352`? Don't you mean `y = 32`? On a general issue: When using an image of shape `(384, 384)`, and restoring a border of 32 pixels on all sides, your mask should have shape `(320, 320)`!?

Comment: Numpy slicing uses y,x syntax. So mask2[y:y + ww, x:x + hh] = mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the middle of the image black without creating a black image and overlaying it or anding it, just use Numpy slicing:

```
import cv2

# Load image and get its dimensions
im = cv2.imread('paddington.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
h,w = im.shape[0:2]

# Make middle black
im[32:h-32, 32:w-32, :] = 0

cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]

Here's a thumbnail of how he used to be in case anyone doesn't know:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to add a mask to your image.

```py
import cv2


# image = cv2.imared("path to image")  # (384x384X3)
image = np.ones((384, 384, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 150  # creating 3d image with pixel value 150

h, w, c = image.shape

border_padding = 32  # border width and height you want to set

# we will set pixel value to zero from [32: 384-32, 32: 384-32]
image[border_padding:h-border_padding, border_padding:w-border_padding] = 0  # black mask image
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T6cr.jpg)